# Require.js: load file from build but don't execute it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, ember.js, requirejs

I'm working on an application that combines ember.js and jquery-mobile.js

In order to make those two play nice with each other, I need to load JQM after Ember is initialized. So I use the following code in my main file, app.js:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'resources/js/',
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths: {
        text: 'lib/require/text',
        ember: 'lib/ember-1.5.1.min',
        jquery: 'lib/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        mobile: 'lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min',
        handlebars: 'lib/handlebars-1.3.0.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'ember': {
            deps: ['handlebars', 'text', 'jquery']
        }
    }
});


define('app', [
    'jquery',
    'app/many/files',
    'ember'
], function($,
    ManyFiles) {

    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
    });

    App = Ember.Application.create({
        ready: function() {
            require(['mobile']);
        }
    });

    // Initialize stuff...
}
```

(As you can see, jqm is loaded only when the ember application is ready)

This works great, but when I build all the files into a single minified js file, I run into this problem: As soon as the code requires JQM, I see an http call on the network tab which goes to grab jquery-mobile.js

Of course this is an unpleasant process. The only solution I can think of is to load JQM along with all the other dependencies but not execute it. Then, the code can execute JQM instead of requiring the file.

However I am not experienced on require.js and I have no idea on how to do that. Any help is appreciated. Other methods to accomplish the same thing are also appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Why does JQM needs to get loaded after Ember?
Because JQM add wrappers, classes and events on the DOM that interfere with ember... and things get really bad

Comment: I don't know Ember - could you clarify why the jQuery Mobile script can't be loaded before Ember is initialised (like the jQuery script)? Maybe that need could be avoided. Failing that, the jQuery Mobile script would need to be minified into a different script from where the Ember script is minified to so that it can be loaded separately at a different point in time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I edited the post to answer your question

Comment: Thanks for that. And to check I understand the problem: the fundamental issue here is that when all the scripts are minified, the mobile script scripts minified along with the ember script, and so they both get loaded at the same time and there is no opportunity to bind the `mobileinit` event handler before loading the mobile script. Is that what you're seeking to solve?

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: So that leads to one more question: how are you doing the minification - what minification tool are you using? Can you control whatever minification tool you're using so that the scripts are minified and output in a particular order?

Comment: People are probably going to start throwing pitchforks at me for even suggesting this, but you could `eval` a minified version of JQM within your ready callback... Just store it as a string variable in the same file (maybe the penultimate line?), that way you don't need to load it externally. It's the laziest solution (so you can try it quickly) I can think of without any obvious drawback or security risk.

Comment: @chrisg I use r.js to do the minification, i'm not sure at the level of control that i can have over it.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I appreciate the effort but I prefer a "clean" way of doing this :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot o fiddling I found out an answer to my problem:

```
    ...

    App = Ember.Application.create({
        ready: emberInit
    });

    // Initialize stuff
}

function emberInit() {
    require(['mobile']);
}
```

It seems like the require statement was too nested for it to work normally (maybe a bug?)

**NOTE:**
While trying to find an answer to my problem I found out about a functionality of require.js that I would like to share with people that might have a similar problem and bump into this thread:

Apparently you can set a callback on the require configuration to run when all dependencies are loaded, like that:

```
require.config({
    deps: ['jquery', 'handlebars', 'ember', 'socketio'],
    callback: function () {
        // Do stuff when above dependencies load
    },
});
```

which was not EXACTLY what I needed, but others might find helpfull